# How to transform Google sheet filter function in apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function filter in a cell, how can I transform it in an apps script function with parameters like range, condition1, condition2?

This is the filter function:

```
=FILTER(Master!B:C; month(Master!B:B) = 1; Master!A:A = true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert the formula of `=FILTER(Master!B:C; month(Master!B:B) = 1; Master!A:A = true)` to Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet, and save the script. And, please set the source and destination sheet names.

```js
const filterValues = v => v.filter(([a, b]) => a === true && b.getMonth() == 0).map(([, ...v]) => v);

// Please run this script.
function myFunction() {
  // Retrieve values from the source sheet and filter values.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master"); // Please set source sheet name.
  const values = srcSheet.getRange("A1:C" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const result = filterValues(values);

  console.log(result); // You can see the filtered values in the log.

  // Put filtered values to the destination sheet.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set destination sheet name.
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
```

- When this script is run, the same values with the above formula are retrieved and put into the destination sheet.
- In this sample, you can also use `filterValues` as a custom function like `=filterValues(Master!A1:C)`.

#### Note:

- About putting the filtered values to the destination sheet, this is a sample script. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)